# Migrate from GenerationType.TABLE to GenerationType.SEQUENCE

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

We are facing a migration from an old `Postgres database` created from `Spring` with `GenerationType.TABLE` to `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`.

Due to big loads of data already loaded on the database, `we want to modify the database schema` to fit `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`, `without dropping it and creating it again.`

If we do not make any change at database (just at code, setting GenerationType.SEQUENCE) and use the old database, we found this message on Eclipse stacktrace:

> ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-32) ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
>   Position: 17

We have looked for `"hibernate_sequence"` on the new database, but we found nothing.

Has anyone some information about what we have to do on the old database (the destination one) to get this working?

Also, where can we find the `"hibernate_sequence"` object Spring is looking for?

### **EDIT**

We have just found that pg_catalog.pg_sequences contains the following:

```
    select * from pg_catalog.pg_sequences
```

[image: select * from pg_catalog.pg_sequences]

Comment: Exactly how do you think Hibernate will chose ID's for your objects when moving from TABLE to SEQUENCE? Before understanding this and the follow-up requirement of a sequence table it is not of much use to describe you the solution.

Comment: @Smutje previously, we had a TABLE solution but now we have the need of having unique IDs shared across all tables; that's why we decided to change it to SEQUENCE generation type. We have already normalized existing IDs on destination database. We just need to know how to manually change destination db to use the sequence Spring has created on the newly db.

Comment: So have you followed instructions on how to move to a SEQUENCE strategy (like https://ntsim.uk/posts/how-to-use-hibernate-identifier-sequence-generators-properly)?

Comment: @Smutje thanks for the information. We will try creating the sequence on destination db, to see if there is more changes needed